# Trying to remember a book about elemental powers

Tags: story-identification, telekinesis

In this book the city is controlled by families of powerful elemental or people who can control the elements. The heroine of this book is a female who works for her family's private investigative agency. She ends up being a telekinetic I believe but doesn't know this at first. She gets roped into trying to stop an elemental that has control of fire. She ends up getting help from an elemental that can control the air and has some telekinetic properties. He is called The Hurrican or something like that. If you can help me remember the name of this book that would be wonderful.

Comment: "The Hurrican" or "The Hurrican***e***"?

Comment: I believe it was the Hurrican. But I could be wrong. I feel kinda silly I posted this and the. Ended up finding the title it's "Burn for me" by Ilona Andrews.

Comment: Self-answering is absolutely fine, in fact encouraged.

Answer (score 5):

I feel silly but I figured it out it was "Burn for me" by Ilona Andrews. Thank you everyone

Comment: Great! You can accept your own answer after a few days.